# Xamarin - Could not load machine data

Tags: xamarin, plugins, package, components, xamarin-studio

I cannot login to my Xamarin account while adding component in Xamarin studio.

[image]

After clicking login button I get following error.

[image]

My account is not logged in somehow. What does this mean "could not load machine data". I really don't want to reinstall Xamarin.

Comment: Do you use hackintosh?

Comment: Yes. I am using hackintosh

Comment: I've got same problem on my hackintosh machine; recognizing the XS logs I can say that Xamarin Studio tries to load some hardware info (probably mac-address of WLAN card) - and it fails on most hackintosh computers. What I can suggest is to just download the content of a component from [Component Store](https://components.xamarin.com/) and put it into project directory..